# How to use OnFinishedPlaying with c++ programing in ue4?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to fire callback when the character animation end.But it doesn't work for me.Do i use it worng?Or we have another solution.Please help.Thanks.

```
// SoldierCharacter.h

UFUNCTION(Category = "Callback")
void FinishedPlaying();



// SoldierCharacter.cpp

 void ASoldierCharacter::BeginPlay()
 {
     Super::BeginPlay();
     GetSprite()->OnFinishedPlaying.AddDynamic(this, &ASoldierCharacter::FinishedPlaying);
 }

 void ASoldierCharacter::FinishedPlaying()
 {
     if (GEngine)
     {
         GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 5.0f, FColor::Red, "Work");
     }
 }
```